# Адаптивный Slick

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

Столкнулась в такой проблемой - нет адаптивности слайдера. Картинки все слипаются  и выглядит это не очень. Подскажите как решить проблему?

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,               
  dots: false,
  arrows:false,
  infinite: true, 
  //variableWidth: true,  
  centerMode:true
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="slider">
    <div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать owl-carousel. Там всё адаптивно и можно менять количество элементов в зависимости от ширины экрана вот так:
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
   items: 5,
   nav:true,
   responsiveClass:true,
   responsive:{
    0:{
     items:1,
    },
    768:{
     items:3,
    },
    920:{
     items:4,
    },
    1200:{
     items:5,
    }
   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

После `centerMode:true`, добавляем такое свойство:

```
responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024, // - от какой ширины изменять настройки(1024 и ниже)
      settings: {
        // вносим изменения на ширине 1024 и ниже 
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480, // брекпоинтов может быть сколько угодно
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
  ]
```

Таким способом можно менять любые настройки слайдера на различных экранах

Comment: спасибо, но не работает. все по прежнему

Comment: Киньте как вы добавили в свой код то, что я написал.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Samoilenko/pen/aKBYJW. здесь работает идеально, но у меня только при Ipad Pro картинок остается три, а все остальные настройки сбрасываются, при уменьшение экрана. не знаю что это за магия такая. ошибок не выдает

Comment: Что сбрасывает?   Ведь эти настройки и так по умолчанию:          
`
  dots: false,
  arrows:false,
  infinite: true, 
`          
И все остается как нужно при уменьшении экрана(если фотографии нужного размера)
https://codepen.io/mishana/pen/wXgJRo
Попробуйте добавить max-width для картинок